# Ipython notebook in PyCharm - have to press Run twice to get result

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am testing the ipython notebook implementation in PyCharm. There is this really annoying issue I am encountering. I open .ipynb file, let us suppose it's empty and I see In[] on the left. I type print 'aaa' and press run. Nothing happens, except the next cell is created below with In[] on the left. If I go up and press run again. the In[] goes to In[1] and it prints 'aaa'. I always have to press Run twice to get results. So what am I missing.

Comment: not related but were you able to find a way to run all the cells ? thanks !